# How can I configure Sql Developer 3 to use cursor keys and the Tab key to navigate around the data window?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I recently upgraded to SQL Developer 3.0.04 because I was having great trouble with an earlier version. It was crashing and freezing all the time.

So far I have found SQL Developer 3 great except for one problem: The cursor and tab keys do not work for navigating around the grid in the data window.

Can someone tell me if there is some easy way to navigate around the data window?
Alternatively is there some configuration that I can make to activate the cursor and tab keys to work in the way that they did in the previous version?

I read this but unfortunately I could not find the "Accelerators" preferences that is talked about in the article : http://www.jroller.com/agileanswers/entry/cursor_movement_in_oracle_s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3.0.04 the **Accelerators** settings are called **Shortcut Keys** and you can find them in **Tools** menu → **Preferences**.

The earlier versions of SQL Developer occasionally "forgot" the accelerator/shortcut key settings and I needed to reset these. It might still happen it seems, as the cursor and tab keys should work as you expected. You can try to "reset" the configuration by clicking on **More action** button in the **Shortcut Keys** (upper right corner) and select **Load Keyboard Scheme** and then selecting **Default**. This has worked well for me so far.